# FlexCard: How to pass records from data source to the dropdown select list?

Tags: omniscript, datasource, industry-cloud

I have created a Flexcard with a DataRaptor as a data source. The records from the datasource are retrieved correctly and are displayed in a datatable as shown in the picture using {records}. I want to have the ability to select only one of the retrieved records so I utilized the select dropdown. In the options of the select dropdown I set the "options" attribute to {records} but it will not show anything. I have transformed the structure of the records to be an array with each element having a label and a value and it is successfully shown in the datatable but not in the select dropdown. How can this be achieved?

[image]